# adding stack panels programmatically with info from a dataTable c#

Tags: c#, wpf

i'm new to WPF and would appreciate it if you help me solve this problem.

The project displays all subjects linked to a student. I am currently trying to display the most recent comments per subject from my database. i have a grid with loaded information and I have a dataTable with the 3 most recent comments of each subject, and would like to add it into the same line of the table but below each other. I have considered using a grid with stack panels for each comment i'm adding. the Stack panels would occupy the 1st row and the 2nd row would contain a button to view all comments. Or just adding the comments to a textBlock. Which would be better?

Bare in mind. if only one comment is available then only that comment must display with the button.

All help will be greatly appreciated

Example of what I'm trying to do:
[image: example of what I'm trying to do]

Comment: Where's the question ?

Comment: The Question is, how can I display the 3 comments in the format of the example. i have the comments saved in a DataTable. I don't want to display the Subject name and ID and stuff 3 times. just once with the 3 comments.  i Have the SubjectID and Subject Name in, just don't know how to display the 3 comments in the same row as that.

Comment: Well what have you tried so far ?, if you could include your code attempts that would be helpful,we're going to guess the structure of your app.